# Login command in docker when using gmail account

Tags: docker, authentication, push, dockerhub, repo

I'm getting started with docker so have created my account on docker hub with my gmail account, have creaeted even a repo there. Now I want to push my repo like:
`docker push user_name/my_image:latest`
I get the error:

```
9733ccc39513: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

when searching, I found that I have to login to my account through the terminal. my problem is I have create my account with gmail, so when I tried this found command:
`docker login --email myEmail@gmail.com`
I'm get back this error:
'unknown flag: --email'

Can you please advise something better to push a repo on docker hub?

`docker login --email myEmail@gmail.com`
I'm get back this error:
'unknown flag: --email'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @olakunle for your response. So I disactivated my account created with google Auth to create another one to log in with my username. When I try to connect, I get this error:
`error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/auth": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.`
Seems like the service is not running even though it is running as you can see below:
[image: Daemon running]